# Unable to deploy nuxt app to digital ocean health checks

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

I created a simple & basic nuxt app then from the terminal, i did push it to github repo. then i did link my repo to digital ocean app functionality so it deploys it. The build is successful yet the launch doesn't launch and i get the following errors

```
Deploy Error: Health Checks
Common Causes
App is running slower than expected
Component Issues
apptest - failed to deploy
```

Please note that i didn't configure the environnement variables, i left it to default settings. is it important to do so?

[image]

Edit : here's nuxt js config

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'apptest',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

the digital ocean log is stuck here

```
[appnuxt] [2021-09-11 10:47:59] yarn run v1.22.11
[appnuxt] [2021-09-11 10:47:59] $ nuxt start
[appnuxt] [2021-09-11 10:48:01] ℹ Listening on: http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Do you have some env variables? You don't need to set those if you don't have any. Also, is your app building successfully locally? Do you build it with `yarn build` and then `yarn start`?

Comment: Yes without a single problem !

Comment: What about the build command? Can you share us your `nuxt.config.js` file please?

Comment: it's frustrating i keep getting errors .... yet i didn't edit the app at all. all i did is nuxt create the app then pushed it to github. after that i went do digital ocean to link the repo

Comment: @kissu check the post

Comment: @kissu anything????

Comment: Everything looks okay so far. Did you tried reaching `www.your-website.com:8080`?

Comment: @kissu yes , it says this site can't be reached

Comment: i solved the problem by opening a ticket. the support redirected me to this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-deploy-error-health-checks-deploycontainerhealthchecksfailed?answer=64947

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article was helped me with the previous setup of the Nuxt.js app:
[Deploy Nuxt.js on DigitalOcean App Platform](https://dev.to/tillsanders/deploy-nuxt-js-on-digitalocean-app-platform-in-5-minutes-or-less-2dij)

As it was mentioned there, it needs to set the run command with specifying host/port for the app (by default it launches on http://localhost:3000):

```
npm start -- --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```